# AMQ8145: Connection broken error in IBM MQ

Tags: ibm-mq

I ran the below command in AIX system and getting below error, It was working before and suddently I'm facing this issue. I ran thin command in non-mqm id.

I tried giving "refresh security" from mqm id and even it is not working.

```
$ print "display qlocal(*) curdepth"|runmqsc TEMP.QMGR
5724-H72 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 1994, 2005.  ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.
Starting MQSC for queue manager TEMP.QMGR.


AMQ8145: Connection broken.

No MQSC commands read.
No commands have a syntax error.
All valid MQSC commands were processed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this code is returned after attempting to runmqsc to a QMgr that is quiescing.  You should `dspmq` to see what WMQ thinks the status of the QMgr is and look in /var/mqm/errors to see if there are any FDC files associated with the error.

If the QMgr is quiescing because it was stopped with `endmqm -w` or `endmqm -i` then you can issue `endmqm -p` which will sever all outstanding connections and shut down the QMgr preemptively.  Then you can restart it and the command should work.

If the `-p` option doesn't work, please see *[Stopping queue managers manually](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/fa22290_.htm)* in the Infocenter.  This tells you which order to kill processes in if a QMgr gets hung.

**Be sure to use the Infocenter for your version of WebSphere MQ because the processes and kill order change between versions!**

Comment: $dspmq
QMNAME(TEMP.QMGR)                                STATUS(Running)

I can able to attempt runmqsc from mqm id ,but facing this problem with all non-mqm id's . i don't see any FDC related to this error or any errors in QMGR logs. MQ Version:     6.0.2.1

Comment: Are the non-mqm IDs in the mqm group?

Comment: You bounce the QMgr yet?  If so then at this point I'd say to open a PMR. You have 21 days left to get support on V6.x then it is end of life. Typically the only time we see IDs in the mqm group not gaining access to the QMgr are if there's a resource error (out of disk or memory) or if the QMgr has both local and remote passwd files (such as NIS+) and the UIDs or GIDs differ. The Support folks can help sort out the more squirrely situations like this.

Comment: No I didn't bounce it yet.  OK..I will open a PMR. Thanks.

Comment: It is permission issue on runmqsc file. we changed it and it worked. Thanks.